# Выполнение команды perl в перловом скрипте

Tags: perl

Будут ли какие-либо проблемы с такой реализацией:

В <> печатается текст (а по факту), который выглядит как если бы я открыл терминал и написал:

```
perl -e '
...
...
'
```

В каждую переменную присваивается некая строка, которая в дальнейшем должна отработать из перлового скрипта, используя:

```
`perl -e '
 $var
 $var2
 $var3
 '`;
```

Корректно ли будет работать данная конструкция?

Comment: а что если прийдёт что-то вроде условного `$var = " '; rm -rf /; perl -e ' "`?

Comment: Я не против, ведь пользователь сам решает что вводить...

Comment: Зачем использовать внешний интерпретатор, если можно выполнять все прямо внутри данного с помощью eval. И вы уверены что вы не против того, что пользователь сам решит удалить все файлы на вашем диске ?

Comment: А при вызове интерпертатора таким образом вы должны быть уверены, что нигде к командах нет одинарных кавычек, иначе они вступят в конфликт с кавычками в командной строке.

Comment: @Mike, нет, я не должен быть уверен. Отдаю это пользователю. Он должен знать

Comment: а вы попробуйте написать код не используя ни одной одинарной кавычки. в принципе ничего сложного, но дико не привычно. если уж позволяете пользователю вводить произвольный код то надо бы и подумать о его удобстве и заэкранировать кавычки перед передачей командному интерпретатору

Comment: @Mike, я пишу не KISS приложение)

Comment: Ладно. ваше дело. Вы спросили "корректно ли будет работать данная конструкция". Ответ: Да, корректно, при правильном ограничении входных данных со стороны пользователя. Но с eval было бы на порядок проще

Comment: @Mike, хочу, чтобы скрипт-кидди не смогли её даже настроить, не говоря уже о пользовании.